# Why I cannot see the block file in the path specified by dfs.data.dir?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Just now I wrote a 90M file into hdfs, and execute command fsck below. The output is below.

```
xuhang@master:~$ hadoop fsck /home/xuhang/hadoopinput/0501/baidu_hadoop.flv -files -blocks -locations
```

/home/xuhang/hadoopinput/0501/baidu_hadoop.flv 103737775 bytes, 2 block(s)
.......................

```
0. blk_-7625024667897507616_12224 len=67108864 repl=2 [node1:50010, node2:50010]
1. blk_2225876293125688018_12224 len=36628911 repl=2 [node1:50010, node2:50010]
```

.................
.................
FSCK ended at Sun Sep 22 11:55:51 CST 2013 in 25 milliseconds

I have configured the same property in hdfs-site.xml to two datanodes like below.

```
<name>dfs.name.dir</name>
<value>/home/xuhang/hadoop-1.2.1/name1,/home/xuhang/hadoop-1.2.1/name2</value>
```

But I find nothing in `/home/xuhang/hadoop-1.2.1/name1` and `/home/xuhang/hadoop-1.2.1/name2` in two datanodes. Why？ I am sure I have wrote the 90M file into hdfs successfully because I can read it from hadoop command or java client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see those blocks are in hosts node1 and node2. Have you been looking at node1 and node2?
Please check the *hdfs-site.xml* in both node1 and node2 too. It's likely that `dfs.data.dir` may be set to something different in those nodes. You should find the *blk_* files inside a directory named *current*, which is inside the directories pointed by `dfs.data.dir`.

Comment: I have been looking at node1 and node2. The configuration is right. I think maybe I have to debug the source code.